# How should I use the react-route-dom function to create a sub-route

Tags: reactjs

I am a freshman to Reactjs. I was following a guide to create a test project step by step. But my sub-route does not work. Is there anybody can help me troubleshoot my code?

The following code is the page.

```
/*eslint-disable*/
// import React,{lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import Css from '../../../assets/css/home/home/index.css';

import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import asyncComponent from '../../../components/async/AsyncComponent';
const IndexComponent=asyncComponent(()=>import('../index/index'));


export default class HomeComponent extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/home/index" Component={IndexComponent}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </React.Fragment>

                <div className={Css['bottom-nav']}>
                    <ul>
                        <li className={Css["home"]+" "+Css["active"]}></li>
                        <li className={Css["text"]+ " "+Css["active"]}>Home</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li className={Css["cart"]}></li>
                        <li className={Css["text"]}>Cart</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li className={Css["mine"]}></li>
                        <li className={Css["text"]}>Mine</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the page should show in the Route area.

```
/*eslint-disable*/
import React from 'react';
// import Css from "../../../assets/css/home/home.css";


export default class IndexComponent extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                home page
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Is there any error in my coding?

Comment: you want to load IndexComponent for both routes i.e.,  /home, /index?

Comment: The first code will be link to the root, "/". I need the second code shows on the first code to be a part of the page. The IndexComponent use the link "/home/index"